# Scheme morphisms from $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, functors

On Mumford-Oda's book on algebraic geometry it says that the association that given a scheme $X$ gives the morphisms on the cathegory of schemes from $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ to $X$ is not a faithful functor, because the set of morphisms is small.

I am trying to prove this fact and it seems simple, but I could not prove it.

Comment: Consider $X=\operatorname{Spec} k$ for different fields $k$. What are the morphisms in this case?

Comment: @bertram I get that $\text{Spec}(k)$ is a one-point set

Comment: @bertram And, for example, there are no ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, so no morphisms from $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ to $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, correct??

Comment: Correct!...................